# Why can't I install from PPAs?

Tags: installation, ppa

just new in using ubuntu, just installed it last night. I having a trouble installing apps using the terminal. When I try to install this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:scopes-packagers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install unity-lens-utilities unity-scope-calculator
```

or this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

I get this:

```
Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --secret-keyring /tmp/tmp.wxeK84wP5F --trustdb-name /etc/apt/trustdb.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80/ --recv FE85409EEAB40ECCB65740816AF0E1940624A220    
gpg: requesting key 0624A220 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: key 0624A220: "Launchpad PPA for TualatriX" not changed
```

that goes for all other apps that I want to install. Any advice guys???
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Just pasting those three lines at the same time won't work. The message you get is only telling you that the GPG keys for that PPA are already stored on your computer.

Try adding the repositories first (first lines), and then do the update/add steps separately with an `&&` between them:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install unity-lens-utilities unity-scope-calculator
```

Answer (score 0):

Between two commands, you have to add `&&`.

Just copying, pasting and executing won't do the trick. If you do that, only the first command get's executed.

Comment: Yes, izx told the same thing 5 hours ago.

Comment: Also, it's not *generally* true that pasting text containing carriage returns into the Terminal won't successfully run it as multiple commands. *Often*, this does work. It fails when commands (besides the last one) are *interactive*. Interactive commands will consume text entered while they are running. Non-interactive commands will not, leaving that text to be consumed by the next interactive process on the shell, which is the shell itself after the command finishes. [`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa` is interactive.](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1091853/)